# Using Map Fragment in view-page-indicator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to use android-support-v4-googlemaps:
https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps
with view-pager-indicator:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Sadly, when I insert map fragment I am receiving an exception (pasted at the end of this
message) and I wasn't able to deduce what is the reason.
I ran example project from android-support-v4-googlemaps and everything was ok.

While I am importing classes from FragmentLayoutMaps (name of example project from android-support-v4-googlemaps) I am able to add
TitlesFragment to my project and everything runs smoothly, but adding
MapFragment throws this exception:

```
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):
java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.viewpagerindicator.sample.MappaTabsActivity
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout
$MapFragment.onCreateView(FragmentLayout.java:245)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:
870)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:
1080)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:
1416)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:
431)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:
139)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:
433)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:
405)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.setCurrentItem(TabPageIndicator.java:
230)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.onMeasure(TabPageIndicator.java:
115)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:
1017)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:842)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-06 17:24:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem can be?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: This is a ViewPager question and not ViewPagerIndicator related.